# huge json file parsing in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

Here's my problem ! I've got a huge json file that I'd like to parse (here's the link : http://pastebin.com/JwPDufMx )
I'd like to extract every song it gets to fill different arrays like ID / TITLE/ GENRE / ARTWORK_URL

I tried this line

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('playlist.json');
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);
for ...  { //don't know how to make this loop to end well despite infinite
$id[$i] = $jfo->tracks->track->id
...
}
```

but it doesn't work.
I'd like to know how to make it right and extract the datas I need :D

thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: the pastebin json is incomplete, is the actual data like this too?

Comment: This is not to mention that clearly the JSON starts with an array wrapper, so if you had complete JSON, you would still likely need to access as `$jfo[i]` (`$jfo` would be a numerically indexed array).

Comment: What "doesn't work?" Doesn't work how? What does your comment about your `for` loop mean?

Comment: Yes the actual data is like this ! It comes from soundcloud API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test data shows that there are multiple playlists. Below code extracts one playlist list at a time by balancing opening and closing brackets. Then use json_decode on each playlist json.

```
$json = file_get_contents('playlist.json');
$depth = 0;
$playlist_json = '';
$tracks = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($json); $i++) {
    $char = $json[$i];
    if ($char == '{') {
        $depth++;
    } elseif ($char == '}') {
        $depth--;
    }

    if ($char == '{' || strlen($playlist_json) > 0) {
        $playlist_json .= $char;
    }

    if ($depth == 0 && strlen($playlist_json) > 0) {
        $playlist = json_decode($playlist_json, true);
        $tracks = array_merge($tracks, $playlist['tracks']);
        $playlist_json = '';
    }
}

foreach ($tracks as $track) {
    echo $track['id'] . "\n";
    echo $track['title'] . "\n";
    echo $track['genre'] . "\n";
    echo $track['artwork_url'] . "\n\n";
}
```

Using it on your test data yields:

```
155675361
Tegan and Sara - I Was A Fool (Bolivard Remix) *FREE DOWNLOAD IN DESCRIPTION*
Deep Pop
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000083195650-0wlzyr-large.jpg?e76cf77

156088370
Mariah Carey - Emotions (LBCK Rmx)
LBCK
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000083458530-wq93hc-large.jpg?e76cf77

156520409
Topi x Tontario - Backfeed
Chill
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000083734122-2i0zh1-large.jpg?e76cf77

157430720
SG Lewis - Silence (Art Of Shades Re-Work)
Sensitive
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000084379509-8dq1aa-large.jpg?e76cf77

156707981
Tender Games - Lost (BBC Radio 1 l Annie Mac - 29.06.2014)
Tender Games
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000083857078-f1axpw-large.jpg?e76cf77

158508920
Sailor & I - Tough Love (Phonothek Remix)
Deep-House
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000085049173-5w358k-large.jpg?e76cf77

158261593
Garde Le Pour Toi

http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000084889721-lhpg98-large.jpg?e76cf77

158384606
Damian Marley - Road To Zion ( EFIX & XKAEM Cover )
deep
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000084969076-tk9e3x-large.jpg?e76cf77

159111023
Clara Moto - In My Dream (Ferdinand Remix)
Ferdinand
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000085458717-m1nhj1-large.jpg?e76cf77
```

Comment: Just... THANK YOU !!! :D Exactly what i was looking, not familiar with json you taught me a lot !

Comment: Is this modification right ?
    foreach ($tracks as $track) {
       $id[$i]=$track['id'];
            $title[$i]=$track['title'];
            $genre[$i]=$track['genre'];
            $artwork[$i]=$track['artwork_url'];
            $i=$i+1;
}

Comment: @Gr3ggz, looks good to me. or you can do `foreach ($tracks as $i => $track) {...}` so you don't need to manually increment `$i`.

Comment: @Gr3ggz, please accept the answer since it has worked for you.

Comment: sorry to up this subject, but would-it be possible to do that with json_decode ? I've heard about the assoc=true that returns an associative array, so maybe it is a faster solution than doing it by hand ?